# Failed to unmarshall yaml

Tags: bash, curl, quoting

I have an execute endpoint that runs a child process which in turn runs a rancher-compose command to start up some containers within a host on rancher. When I hit this `/execute` endpoint from the node app it work fine and starts the containers as expected. When hitting the `/execute` endpoint from a bash script through `cURL` command it fails and gives me the error below. I don't understand why it throws an error that it cannot unmarshall my `yaml` file just when the command is run through a bash script. This is leading me to believe that this is not an issue with my `yaml` file. Below I put the error and the command that's failing and the `cURL` command i'm using.

I'm absolutely lost and any help would be greatly appreciated!

> ERROR starting job, unable to run sub-process for container deployment. >ERR=Error: Command failed: /rancher-tools/rancher-compose --project-name mic-iwbl3g97 --verbose --file docker-compose-job-submitter.yml up -d
>
> job deployment output: time="2016-12-05T04:35:49Z" level=debug msg="Environment Context from file : map[]" time="2016-12-05T04:35:49Z" level=debug msg="Opening compose file: docker-compose-job-submitter.yml" time="2016-12-05T04:35:49Z" level=debug msg="Looking for stack mic-iwbl3g97" time="2016-12-05T04:35:49Z" level=info msg="Creating stack mic-iwbl3g97" time="2016-12-05T04:35:49Z" level=error msg="Failed to unmarshall: yaml: unmarshal errors:\n line 15: cannot unmarshal !!str NaN into int64\n line 16: cannot unmarshal !!str NaN into int64\ncommand:\n- mic-iwbl3g97\n- NaN\n- $input_csv_file\n- $start_year\n- $end_year\ncontainer-name: mic-iwbl3g97\ncpu_shares: 25\nimage: $repo_name:$tag\nlabels:\n io.rancher.container.pull_image: always\n io.rancher.container.start_once: true\n io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:host_label: MIC-Use=TPC_Modeling\n io.rancher.sidekicks: locking, input, output, param, input-helper\nmem_limit: NaN\nmemswap_limit: NaN\nnetwork_mode: none\nvolumes_from:\n- input\n- output\n- param\n- locking\n"

```
curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"S3_param_file":"$input_csv_file", "memory_constraint":"$memory_constraint", "time_constraint":"$time_constraint", "start_year":"$start_year", "end_year":"$end_year", "tag":"$tag", "repo":"$repo_name"}' http://my_ip_address:3000/execute
```

Comment: What's the YAML meant to look like? Doesn't YAML have significant whitespace, could that be causing the unmarshalling error?

Comment: It does, but i'm skeptical it's the issue because it works properly when called from the web app as opposed to a bash script using a `cURL`. I've also tested it using many yaml checkers.

Comment: Parameters will not expand in single quotes: `echo '$hello'` prints `$hello`.

Comment: @andlrc, I have my parameters in double quotes as you can see?

Comment: @Mihado No: `curl ...-d '{"S3_param_file":"$input_csv_file" ...`

Comment: @andlrc I'm not following, can you elaborate briefly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables will not be expanded in single quotes, use double quotes to expand:

```
curl -s -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"S3_param_file":"'"$input_csv_file"'", "memory_constraint":"'"$memory_constraint"'", "time_constraint":"'"$time_constraint"'", "start_year":"'"$start_year"'", "end_year":"'"$end_year"'", "tag":"'"$tag"'", "repo":"'"$repo_name"'"}' \
  http://my_ip_address:3000/execute
```

See how i swap between single quotes and double quotes:

```
'{"json_here": "'"$parameter_here"'"}'
sssssssssssssssssdddddddddddddddddssss
```

Where `s` represent single quotes, and `d` represent double quotes.

At evidenced above it quickly becomes a mess, one can however use jq to create JSON:

```
$ jq -n --arg a "a val" --arg b 'b val'  '{$a, $b}'
{
  "a": "a val",
  "b": "b val"
}
```

Comment: IT WORKED! You sir, are my hero!

Comment: @Mihado I'm happy it worked for you. If you consider reading http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes